# Mysql Server : Unable to start server 5.7 (An error occurred while trying to start the MySQL Server instance.)

Tags: mysql

Beginning configuration step:

Starting Server
Attempting to start service MySQL57

An error occurred while trying to start the MySQL Server instance.

Ended configuration step: Starting Server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. After opening the Firewall Ports it runs.

Comment: From my point of view this is not a good answer, please ask @MedMerrou next time in a comment on his question, whether he tried this.